# CreateProcess: cmd.exe does not exit when child process is finished

Tags: windows, delphi, createprocess, delphi-10.3-rio

I have this following code that execute Windows *cmd.exe* passing *powershell.exe* as argument.

The problem is that *cmd.exe* is not terminated after *powershell.exe* finalization.

How do I fix that?

```
function ExecAndWait(const FileName, Params: string;
  const WindowState: Word): Boolean;
var
  SUInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CmdLine: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  CmdLine := '"' + FileName + '"' + Params;
  FillChar(SUInfo, SizeOf(SUInfo), #0);
  with SUInfo do
  begin
    cb := SizeOf(SUInfo);
    dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    wShowWindow := WindowState;
  end;
  Result := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, False,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil,
    PChar(ExtractFilePath(FileName)), SUInfo, ProcInfo);
  if Result then
  begin
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
  end;
end;
```

---

**Edit:**

```
var
  MyFolder, Command: string;
begin
  MyFolder := '"' + ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName) + '"';
  Command := '/K  powershell.exe Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath ''' + MyFolder + '''';
  ExecAndWait('c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe', #32 + Command, SW_HIDE);
end;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are calling `ExecAndWait()`. But, why are you executing `cmd.exe` at all? You should be executing `powershell.exe` (or any other `.exe`) directly instead. There is no point in executing `cmd.exe` unless you are executing actual console commands that are not implemented as their own `.exe`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that *cmd.exe* is not terminated after *powershell.exe* finalization.

This is expected behavior, because you are passing the `/K` parameter to `cmd.exe`:

> /K      Carries out the command specified by string **but remains**

That means `cmd.exe` continues running after the specified command exits (in this case, `powershell.exe`), until the user types in `exit` or closes the command window.

If you want `cmd.exe` to exit after `powershell.exe` exits, use the `/C` parameter instead:

> /C      Carries out the command specified by string **and then terminates**

However, you really should not be using `cmd.exe` at all to execute `powershell.exe`, you should instead be executing `powershell.exe` directly, eg:

```
var
  MyFolder, Command: string;
begin
  MyFolder := AnsiQuotedStr(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName), '"');
  Command := 'Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath ' + QuotedStr(MyFolder);
  ExecAndWait('<path to>\powershell.exe', #32 + Command, SW_HIDE);
end;
```

---

On a side note: I would strongly recommend updating `ExecAndWait()` to handle the `#32` between the `FileName` and `Params` values, don't require the caller to handle that, eg:

```
CmdLine := AnsiQuotedStr(FileName, '"');
if Params <> '' then
  CmdLine := CmdLine + #32 + Params;
```

Alternatively:

```
CmdLine := TrimRight(AnsiQuotedStr(FileName, '"') + #32 + Params);
```